# laravel mutator increment number when we get the record

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model called Alsolike , i want when we get the data from the database i want to increment number of views, to know how many times the record viewed  , here is what i tried to do , also if there is a good approche, suggest

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Alsolike extends Model
{
    public function getMealidAttribute($value)
    {
        $user = App\Alsolike::first()->increment('view');;
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach looks good. But when it comes to webside statistic I would recommend another tool as Goolge Analitics.

Comment: my project manager , he dont want Google Analytics

Comment: So I would make like this: Put boosting number of viewsin this page controller in constructor. Then each time, when page would be showed the constructor does it job. Maybe like that?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker However of you want this approach: A `mutator` should follow `setFooAttribute` you mean an `accessor`? In that case, don't forget to return the attribute itself!

Comment: you mean return $value 
public function getMealidAttribute($value)
    {
        $user = App\Alsolike::first()->increment('view');;
  $user->save();
  return $value;
    }
}

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, otherwise you will no longer be able to `get` Mealid

Comment: but after i get the data from php artisan tinker the value of view not changed
App\Alsolike::where('meal_id', '8')->first();

Comment: where are you accessing the mealid attribute (dynamic property), as that accessor doesn't run unless you try to access it.    ... also  `increment` does a query and updates that incremented var on the instance

Comment: so how should i access the mealid to make accessor work , can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

> ...also if there is a good [approach], suggest...

I think the `middleware` approach fits better in your scenario. Create a middleware, like `IncrementViews`, that will increment the number of views for your `AlsoLike` model every time a route is visited.

You may also want to limit or filter how your views will be incremented, maybe try to create a table to save the `ip addresses` of your users then check if the same `ip address` has already visited the page for a number of minutes.